# Is it possible to use a font in the terminal that isn't monospace

Tags: command-line, fonts

Yeah, so there's the question. I wondered if it was possible to use the Ubuntu font in the terminal. I know how to change the font, but using anything except a monospace font doesn't really work very well. Is there a way to use a non-monospace font where it looks ok?

Comment: I suggest you look at [this similar question](http://superuser.com/a/357579) asked on Super User.

Comment: It's possible and it looks ugly. As you said, "anything except a monospace font doesn't really work very well". So why are you looking into this possibility? Could you make that clear by editing your question?

Comment: Why am I looking into this possibility? Maybe I don't have a why, maybe I'm just curious!

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible? Yes.
*(However, not for Konsole - it prevents you to select non-monospaced fonts.)*

Does it work well? No. Output formatting is relying on a monospaced font to make it look as designed (tabular output for example).

Comment: ok, but HOW? I got a font (ttf-fixedsys-excelsior) which is nearly monospaced (it is monospaced for all original Fixedsys characters, except for some ligatures), but I'm not able to make it appear among the fonts selectable by the gnome terminal. I am willing to edit .fonts.conf or to use FontForge.

Comment: sorry, the name of the nearly monospaced font is Fixedsys Excelsior

Comment: yeah, HOW. This is not actually an answer.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Please ask a NEW question on how to configure a fond in your terminal application (please specify what you use, etc.). The original question was different to yours, it seems.