# Custom fonts not working correctly in the terminal

Tags: fonts

I just installed Ubuntu and, upon opening the terminal, I tried to customize it; everything works fine, except when I try to use a custom font, in which case the spacing between letters is completely messed up:

[image]

What can the problem be? I tried various fonts, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't use monospace font in terminal. See [more here](http://askubuntu.com/a/189351/269282).

Comment: Thank you, I used Liberation Mono and it works wonderfully.